# selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@itemprop='email']"}

Tags: selenium

I tried to get company mail address from website, i made a loop to handel this job but the probleem is not all company's has mail address, that occurs a problem. My code is read email address,

```
email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@itemprop='email']")).getText();
```

i just tried with this method to handel this problem but no result

```
public static String getEmail(String email){
            if(email.equals("")){
                email="No Email";
            }   

            return email;
    }
```

Can somebody help me how can i fix this problem, i just want that if company has no email address just put the text "No Email" 
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need try catch around the "find_element". Selenium will throw NoSuchElementException if you try to access an element which is not in the DOM